# Shell script function parameter with double quote that ECHO command's SIGN

Tags: shell

I'm developing some shell script. please help me

I want to highlight specific strings with FUNCTION like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
function echoWithColor(){
    local InputString=${1}
    tput bold;tput setaf 2   # make words color to bright green
    echo ${InputString}
    tput sgr0                # make words color to default
}

echoWithColor "Hello everyone!"
```

this works, but **I want to add some blank (space text) at end of line** like

```
echo -n "Input your age : "; read AGE
```

> [root@mycomputer scripts]# ./script.sh
>
> Input your age : 9999

but

```
#!/bin/bash
function echoWithColor(){
    local InputString=${1}
    tput bold;tput setaf 2   # make words color to bright green
    echo ${InputString}
    tput sgr0                # make words color to default
}

echoWithColor "-n Input your age : "; read AGE
```

> [root@mycomputer scripts]# ./script.sh
>
> Input your age :9999

Nope

.

```
#!/bin/bash
function echoWithColor(){
    local InputString=${1}
    tput bold;tput setaf 2   # make words color to bright green
    echo ${InputString}
    tput sgr0                # make words color to default
}

echoWithColor "-n \"Input your age : \""; read AGE
```

> [root@mycomputer scripts]# ./script.sh
>
> "Input your age :"9999

Escaping? Nope.

How can I add blank text at end of line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you don't quote your variables:

```
var="    my value    "
echo $var without quotes   # writes: my value without quotes
echo "$var with quotes"    # writes:    my value     with quotes
```

Since you want to pass pass multiple strings to echo (both `-n` and `Input your age`), you should rewrite the function to take multiple arguments (`"$@"`) instead of just one (`$1`), and then make sure to quote when using them:

```
#!/bin/bash
echoWithColor(){
    local InputStrings=( "$@" ) 
    tput bold;tput setaf 2   # make words color to bright green
    echo "${InputStrings[@]}"
    tput sgr0                # make words color to default
}

echoWithColor -n "Input your age: "
```

Now `echoWithColor`  works exactly like `echo`, and preserves all spaces you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add space ' ' in `echo ${InputString}` command  in function just like below

```
#!/bin/bash
function echoWithColor(){
    local InputString=${1}
    tput bold;tput setaf 2   # make words color to bright green
    echo ${InputString}' ' 
    tput sgr0                # make words color to default
}

echoWithColor "-n Input your age : "; read AGE
```

Comment: I'm really want to accept both, but this system disallowed :(